# How to change Django views dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
# In views.py
num = 1

def home(request):
    global num
    context = {
        'num1': num
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)

# In home.html
<h1>{{ num1 }}</h1>
```

I have my program set up so that the variable `num` is changed to a random integer between 0 and 9 every 5 seconds (I haven't showed that code here for simplicity), and I know it works because I am also printing the value of `num` every  5 seconds and it is changing.  However, in home.html I am only seeing "1", so num1 is not changing.  How would I have num1 change to equal the new value for `num`?

Answer (score 0):

youd have to pass the updated num to the view so that it can "re-render" the updated template variable. it is only rendering the initial because that is what is passed in context when you have rendered your template using render(...)

javascript would probably be a better job for this imo.

Comment: How would I use javascript, can you please show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the template is rendered using the `num` value `1` everytime. You might be changing the value of `num` later but once a template has been rendered, it won't change the value of `num` automatically in your template. You would have to do it explicitly.

You can use javascript as [@Slayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5230901/slayer) also mentioned to update the value of `num` in your template every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The view is processed only once. Once the template is rendered, the view won't be executed again. If you want a random number to generated on the front-end every 5 seconds, execute it on the front-end itself. You need not hit the backend again and again for this. It would just overload your server with requests.

Here is the javascript code for a random number generator:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```